# Simulating Mouse event in Microsoft Edge for d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, microsoft-edge

I'm writing tests and trying to simulate a "mousemove" event. The method I am using which works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE 10 & 11 is:

```
var e = new MouseEvent('mousemove',{
    "clientX": 250,
    "clientY": 100,
});

myElem.dispatchEvent(e);
```

But it does not work in Edge. The "mousemove" event fires and is caught by my listener, but the position is incorrect. Instead of using the provided coordinates, it appears to use the window origin, 0,0.

My actual code does runs correctly in Edge, so it appears to solely be an issue with simulating the event. But the added complication is this is for a d3 chart and the mouse position is being read with d3.mouse, so I cannot rule out that there is something different in Edge in the interaction between d3.mouse and a mouse event.

Other approaches I have tried include using a CustomEvent and using a PointerEvent, but both seemed to trigger the eventListener, but not even be readable by d3.mouse.

**UPDATE**

Originally I thought that the specified coordinates were completely ignored; this is not the case. The reality is even more bizarre. If I use absurdly high numbers, then I can get it to register over my element. But real numbers are considered waaay off screen.

For example, if my element getBoundingClientRect gives me:

```
left: 100,
top: 10,
width: 500,
height: 300
```

and I use coordinates such as:

```
var e = new MouseEvent('mousemove',{
    "clientX": 350,
    "clientY": 150,
});
```

which should place my cursor over the element, Edge seems to think my cursor it is way off screen. If instead I put in numbers such as:

```
var e = new MouseEvent('mousemove',{
    "clientX": 100000,
    "clientY": 50000,
});
```

Edge will then consider this to be over my element.

Answer (score 0):

The d3.mouse method returns the x,y coordinates of the mouse event relative to the graph container.  The clientX and clientY values you are using to simulate the mouse event provide the x,y coordinates of the mouse event relative to the current window.  So, the coordinate sets are not the same.  You can manually calculate the same coordinate values as the d3.mouse method via:

```
 d3MouseX = clientX - rect.left
 d3MouseY = clientY - rect.top
```

where `rect.left` and `rect.top` are the coordinates of the bounding rectangle for the graph object.  You can get these coordinates with the `e.target.getBoundingClientRect()` method.

Comment: Yes I am doing that. It doesn't matter what values are put in for the mouse event. They are completely ignored.

Comment: @elliot did you try using pageX, pageY coordinates (i.e. event coordinates relative to document origin)?  I personally use that coordinate set when manually calculating D3 events, rather than using the D3 methods.  Just wondering if it might make a difference with MS Edge...